# While reorder the column in slickgrid, the header menu frozen column funtionality not working

Tags: slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

While reorder the column in slickgrid, the header menu frozen column functionality is not working.

The below error thrown in console:

```
zone-evergreen.js:172 Uncaught TypeError: this.sharedService.visibleColumns is not iterable
    at HeaderMenuExtension.executeHeaderMenuInternalCommands (angular-slickgrid.js:10948:1)
    at HeaderMenu.<anonymous> (angular-slickgrid.js:10696:1)
    at Event.notify (slick.core.js:104:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.handleMenuItemClick (slick.headermenu.js:346:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5183:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.$event.dispatch (jquery.event.drag-2.3.0.js:387:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.push.7TqN.$event.dispatch (jquery.event.drag-2.3.0.js:387:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4991:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:400:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168:1)
```

[image]

My grid option

```
public gridOptions: GridOption = {
        enableAutoSizeColumns: false,
        // angular-upgrade
        enableEmptyDataWarningMessage: false,

        autoFitColumnsOnFirstLoad: false,
        autoCommitEdit: true,
        enablePagination: true,
        pagination: {  // Pagination UI - Item per page select options for default pagintation
            pageSizes: [10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 1000, 2000],
            pageSize: 50
        },
        autoEdit: false,
        rowHeight: 40,
        headerRowHeight: 40,
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        editable: true,
        enableAutoResize: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableExcelExport: true,
        enableExport: true,
        i18n: this.translateService,
        gridMenu: {
            hideExportExcelCommand: true,
            hideExportCsvCommand: true,
            customItems: [{
                command: "cspfm-excel-export",
                titleKey: "EXPORT_TO_EXCEL",
                iconCssClass: "fa fa-file-excel-o",
                action: (event, callbackArgs) => {

                    this.slickgridUtils.excelExport(event, callbackArgs, this.tempColumnDefinitions, this)
                }
            }, {
                command: "cspfm-csv-export",
                titleKey: "EXPORT_TO_CSV",
                iconCssClass: "fa fa-download",
                action: (event, callbackArgs) => {
                    this.slickgridUtils.excelExport(event, callbackArgs, this.tempColumnDefinitions, this)
                }
            },
            { divider: true, command: '', positionOrder: 90 },
            {
                command: "cspfm-appm-guide-fetch-mode-fully",
                titleKey: "Full fetch",
                iconCssClass: "icon-mat-explore",
                action: (event, callbackArgs) => {
                    this.dataFetchMode = 'Full';
                    this.fetchModeChanged()
                },
                positionOrder: 91
            }, {
                command: "cspfm-appm-guide-fetch-mode-batch",
                titleKey: "Batchwise fetch",
                iconCssClass: "icon-mat-autorenew",
                action: (event, callbackArgs) => {
                    this.dataFetchMode = 'Batch';
                    this.fetchModeChanged()
                },
                positionOrder: 92
            }, {
                command: "cspfm-appm-guide-fetch-mode-action",
                titleKey: "On click batchwise",
                iconCssClass: "icon-mat-touch_app",
                action: (event, callbackArgs) => {
                    this.dataFetchMode = 'OnClickBatch';
                    this.fetchModeChanged()
                },
                positionOrder: 93
            }, {
                command: "cspfm-toggle-pagination",
                titleKey: "Toggle pagination",
                iconCssClass: "fa fa-bookmark",
                action: (event, callbackArgs) => {
                    this.slickgridUtils.togglePagination(event, callbackArgs, this.gridObj, this.angularGrid)
                },
                positionOrder: 94
            },
            {
                command: "cspfm-groupby",
                titleKey: "Group-by",
                iconCssClass: "icon-mat-account_tree",
                action: (event, callbackArgs) => {
                    this.slickgridUtils.openDraggableGroupingRow(this.onGroupByEnabledObj, this.gridObj, "SearchList")
                },
                positionOrder: 95
            }, {
                command: "cspfm-clear-groupby",
                titleKey: "Clear Grouping",
                iconCssClass: "fa fa-times",
                action: (event, callbackArgs) => {
                    this.slickgridUtils.clearGrouping(this.angularGrid, this.draggableGroupingPlugin, this.gridObj, this.gridOptions, this.filteredResultList, this.gridSearchRowToggle, this.onGroupByEnabledObj, this.filterSectionDetail)
                },
                positionOrder: 96
            }
            ],
            hideClearFrozenColumnsCommand: false
        },
        enableAutoTooltip: true,
        autoTooltipOptions: {
            enableForCells: true,
            enableForHeaderCells: true,
            maxToolTipLength: 1000
        },
        headerMenu: {
            hideColumnHideCommand: true,
            hideFreezeColumnsCommand: false
        },
        autoResize: {
            containerId: this.gridContainerId,
            calculateAvailableSizeBy: 'container'
        },
        exportOptions: {
            exportWithFormatter: true
        },
        excelExportOptions: {
            exportWithFormatter: true,
        },
        enableTranslate: true,
        presets: {
            sorters: [{ columnId: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm138993']['pfm138993_institutename_7']['prop'], direction: 'ASC' }],
        },
        enableAsyncPostRender: true, // for the Angular PostRenderer, don't forget to enable it
        asyncPostRenderDelay: 0,    // also make sure to remove any delay to render it
        params: {
            angularUtilService: this.angularUtilService // provide the service to all at once (Editor, Filter, AsyncPostRender)
        },
        enableDraggableGrouping: true,
        createPreHeaderPanel: true,
        showPreHeaderPanel: false,
        preHeaderPanelHeight: 40,
        draggableGrouping: {
            dropPlaceHolderText: 'Drop a column header here to group by the column',
            deleteIconCssClass: 'fa fa-times',
            onGroupChanged: (e, args) => this.slickgridUtils.onGroupChanged(e, args, this.gridMenuExtension, this.angularGrid, this.tempColumnDefinitions, this.gridObj, this.draggableGroupingPlugin, this.gridOptions, this.layoutId),
            onExtensionRegistered: (extension) => {
                this.draggableGroupingPlugin = extension
            }
        },
        enableColumnReorder: true,
        alwaysShowVerticalScroll: false 
    };
```

Frozen column code in onAngularGridCreated:

```
angularGridReady(angularGrid: AngularGridInstance) {
        this.angularGrid = angularGrid;
        this.gridObj = angularGrid.slickGrid;
        this.angularGrid.gridService.setPinning({ frozenColumn: 2 }, false, true, true);
    }
```

Software Version:

- Angular : 11.2.18
- Angular-Slickgrid : 2.30.4
- TypeScript : 4.0.8
- Operating System : Windows 10
- Node : 14.18.3
- NPM : 6.14.15

Comment: I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid and you seem to be using an old version, I followed the same steps on the latest version and there's no error thrown. So I would suggest you to eventually upgrade to latest version, I'm a single person supporting this project and I will **not** fix bugs on older versions. So unless you upgrade, you're out of luck, sorry